# Regex Formula & Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm working on a google sheet and I need to associate some equipment with a room number.  I'm looking for a pattern in a cell, like this: CS1-4.  The CS will always be before a single number (1-4), followed by a '-' and then followed by 1 or 2 numbers.  So I may have CS1-5 or CS1-12 for example.  Anytime I have CS1-9, I get a #REF error in google sheets.

Here's the code I have now:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS([1-4]-[1-4])"), 220, IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS([1-4]-[5-8])"), 240, IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS([1-4]-[9-12])"), 260, IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS([1-4]-[13-16])"), 280, ""))))
```

It seems like it's only looking at the first number after the dash instead of looking to see if there's two digits after the dash.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation `[9-12]` is not a range from 9-12, it is an invalid range.

The pattern with a number 1-4 and 9-12 can be written as:

```
CS-[1-4]-(9|1[012])
```

And 13-16

```
CS-[1-4]-1[3-6]
```

If you don't want partial matches, you can add word boundaries `\b` to the left and right of the pattern, or us anchors `^` and `$`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up about the 9-12.  I'm still getting a return of '220' when I type CS1-13.  I think it's stopping at CS1-1 and skipping the second digit?

Comment: I think I got it now, I just added a $ at the end of each string.  I now have:

=IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-[1|2|3|4]$"),  220,  IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-[5|6|7|8]$"),  240,  IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[-4]-(9|10|11|12)$"),  260,  IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-13|14|15|16$"), 280, ))))

Comment: @Jump_Ace Correct, or add `\b` instead of `$` and `[1|2|3|4]` is  `[1-4]` or else it can match a `|` char too.

Comment: @Jump_Ace Note that in your answer `CS[1-4]-13|14|15|16$` should be `CS[1-4]-(13|14|15|16)$` or in short `CS[1-4]-1[3-6]$`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
"CS[1-4]-9|10|11|12"
```

[image]

fx:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-9|10|11|12"),  260, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-13|14|15|16"), 280, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-[1-4]"),       220, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-[5-8]"),       240,))))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think its still only looking at the first digit after the '-'.  if I try CS1-12 it still returns '220'.  Any suggestions on how to have it look at up to two digits after the '-'?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jump_Ace formula updated. try now

Answer (score 0):

Here's what is working for me now.

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-[1|2|3|4]$"),  220,  IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-[5|6|7|8]$"),  240,  IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[-4]-(9|10|11|12)$"),  260,  IF(REGEXMATCH(D10, "CS[1-4]-13|14|15|16$"), 280, ))))
```